# Can this capacitor circuit on the left be rewritten as the one on the right

Tags: capacitor, parallel

[image]

In other words, it should be in parallel.

Comment: Yes. The connections are the same.

Comment: try proving that the two circuits are not the same

Comment: OK, in all honesty: this site is called "electrical engineering". The ability to see the two schematics are the same needs to be kind  of required for people to be able to communicate here. My guess is you're in school and are learning about schematics – that's awesome! You'll want to get a book or something that explains basic principles of schematics. The very fundamental principle is that geometric position doesn't matter - all that matters is what is connected to what.

Comment: Oh wait, you've got another question about KCL?! Ok, definitely go back to the very beginning of your studies. This is basic stuff, and you need to be able to instantly see the answer to this question if you even want to be able to understand your exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figures 1a and 1b.*

What's important here is what nodes the components are connected to. It should be clear that in both (a) and (b) above that C2 is connected to A and B in both configurations and that C3 is too. The circuits are equivelant.

Because the ends of both components share common nodes they are deemed to be in parallel. The schematic on the right makes this more obvious and would generally be considered a better way to draw the circuit.

Comment: Yeah, the right circuit makes it easier for me to read as you can obviously see it is in parallel. Thanks.